# Installing any sample application on galaxy GT-6500

Tags: android

Working with Eclipse ADT. My target device is Galaxy GT-S6500 running Android ver. 2.3.6. Set my target ADV to Android 2.3.3 API level 10. When running samples (most of them) on Android emulator it all works fine.

When deploying the .APK file (thru SD Card) on my Galaxy device and try to install it
it comes up with "Application not installed" message.

Comment: Dont put interpretations of the error, instead put the exact error or snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the previously installed application then install it from apk. If you run the application using eclipse then you can not run a released apk without uninstalling that